# Binding to a List<>

Tags: wpf, list, datagrid, binding

I have a datagrid like this:

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
                    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Code" x:Name="columnProductCode" Binding="{Binding Path=Product.ProductCode}" IsReadOnly="True" ></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" x:Name="columnProductName" Binding="{Binding Path=Product.Name}" IsReadOnly="True" ></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductMeasure" x:Name="columnDonViTinh" Binding="{Binding Path=Product.Measure IsReadOnly="True"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
                        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" x:Name="ColumnQuantity" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity IsReadOnly="False"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
                    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

In the behind code, I have a struct like this:

```
private struct ProductDetail
        {

            public TProduct Product { get; set ; } // TProduct is a class provied by a web service
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }
```

and a List like this:

```
        private IList<ProductDetail> bs = new List<ProductDetail>();
```

I had tried to fill data to "bs". And binding like this:

```
this.dg.ItemsSource = this.bs;
```

Everything is ok. I can insert a new row, delete row, but when I try to modified the column Quantity then click on the header of the datagrid (to resort) --> the Quantity column change to it is before.

How can I fix this problem.
Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have try to define a class (with TProduct and Quantity attribute also) instead of the current struct. And .. it works =.=

```
private class ProductDetail
{
    public TProduct Product { get; set ; } // TProduct is a class provied by a web service
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On your datagrid, you must specify that the data changes when you change the property, rather than leave the cell.  To do that, you add the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding and then it should work.  Your DataGrid will now look like this:

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Code"
            x:Name="columnProductCode" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=Product.ProductCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsReadOnly="True" >
        </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name"
            x:Name="columnProductName"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Product.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsReadOnly="True" >
        </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductMeasure"
            x:Name="columnDonViTinh"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Product.Measure, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsReadOnly="True">
        </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity"
            x:Name="ColumnQuantity"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            IsReadOnly="False">
        </dg:DataGridTextColumn>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike Brown and Brent. I have try "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the full API of the DataGrid but I think you have to commit changes before they are pushed back to the underlying object. [Looking at the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(VS.95).aspx) It looks like the edit isn't committed until you change cells or press enter. If you sort before doing either of those actions, the edit might be cancelled.

Comment: Thanks Mike Brown and Brent. I have try "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" but it does not work.